# Compact Famework lock PDA screen

Tags: c#, compact-framework

In windows mobile PDA app is there anyway to show a form full screen, no other PDA system menus, just our form on top in fullscreen and make the user no exit from the form (there will be an exit button in form , they can exit through that) , Like locking a windows application showing in maximized with no titlebar, taskbar , not ctrl-alt-delete, alt-tab etc, as we did in win apps with APIs. I need the same thing in PDA.

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747615/how-to-make-a-mobile-application-stay-on-top) for detailed discussion about this issue.

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747615/how-to-make-a-mobile-application-stay-on-top

Answer (score 1):

Setting the WindowState to Maximized will make the form visually cover the full screen, but will not prevent the user to leave the screen using hardware buttons on the device.

Comment: Anyway to disable hardware buttons

Comment: First answer has a solution i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is at bootup, try using a console app.

Answer (score 0):

In addition if you happen to be using a symbol branded product download their appcenter from http://support.symbol.com

This gives you a lot of control over what the user can do with the system beyond just maxing out the screen, includes password protected settings.